# Why am I receiving a positional argument error when I attempt to populate a database?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently running a script that is supposed to create an SQLAlchemy Database that should be populated by the information below; This DB is linked to a Flask based, tasklist application. I am using SQLAlchemy 2.1.
This is the db_create.py script.

```
# project/db_create.py
from views import db
from models import Task
from datetime import date

# create the database and the db table

db.create_all()
# insert data

db.session.add(Task("Finish this", date(2016, 9, 22), 10, 1))
db.session.add(Task("Finish Python", date(2016, 10, 3), 10, 1))

# commit the changes
db.session.commit()
```

Now specifically I am receiving this error whenever I try to create the database:

```
/Users/Paul/Desktop/RealPython/flasktaskr/ENV/lib/python3
.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:800: UserWarning:    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and   will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "db_create.py", line 8, in <module>
db.session.add(Task("Finish this", date(2016, 9, 22), 10, 1))
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

I have tracked down an init() function in one of the files within the app, maybe this might be of some help to you:

```
def __init__(self, name, due_date, priority, status):
    self.name = name
    self.due_date = due_date
    self.priority = priority
    self.status = status
```

When I run the db_create.py file, the database IS created, however, it fails to populate the DB with the data within that original file.

Why am I receiving the error, and why is the DB failing to populate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `__init__()` method to your sqlalchemy class definition for `Task`

See the [docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/) for an example.

The first positional argument is always self (read about object oriented programming to understand more about that), but essentially this error is saying that you are passing arguments and your class definition doesn't know what to do with them.

Comment: YES! This was it. Specifically, this was the `__init__()` function for `Task` like you said. The problem was the indentation within the class itself.